# Bug I cannot identify

Tags: ruby

I ran this piece of code earlier:

```
require "awesome_print"
require "rexml/document"
require "debugger"

include REXML

class Scrapper
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize
    file = File.new("./cia-1996.xml")
    @data = REXML::Document.new(file)
  end

  def get_country_inflation
    inflation_hash = {}
    XPath.match( data, "//country").map { |element| 
      inflation_hash[element.attributes["name"]] = element.attributes["inflation"].to_i}
      nested_array = inflation_hash.to_a
      sorted_array = nested_array.sort_by {|country, inflation_value| inflation_value}.reverse
      puts "The countries with the highest inflation indexes in 1996 were:"
      first_five = sorted_array.first(5)
      first_five.each do |item|
        puts "#{item[0]}, with an inflation index of #{item[1]}"
      end
    end
  end
end


sample = Scrapper.new
sample.get_country_inflation
```

After making some edits, I now get error message

> economics_challenge.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Can you please give me pointers as to where the mistake/typo might be (been starring at it for a while now and would appreciate feedback from a new set of eyes).

Thank you so much!

Edit: 
so I made the changes suggested but I got more error messages:

```
economics_challenge.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting keyword_end
economics_challenge.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting '}'
...flation_value| inflation_value}.reverse
...                               ^
economics_challenge.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
economics_challenge.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting '}'
```

line 26 refers to the 2nd line in the piece of code below: piece of code (and I think this is where the original problem is):

```
XPath.match( data, "//country").map do |element|
      inflation_hash[element.attributes["name"]] = element.attributes["inflation"].to_i}
end
```

line 29 is:

```
sorted_array = nested_array.sort_by {|country, inflation_value| inflation_value}.reverse
```

I will attempt to fix the error in 29 by calling reverse on sorted array and saving that to a variable.

Line 35 is an end statement and there is no line 46.

Any tips?

Thank you!

2nd Edit:
Wow! I cannot believe I failed to realize that I didn't end many things. I will be sticking to the `do and`end syntax from now on.

Thank you both for helping me out so much … really appreciate it!

Comment: Ruby is telling you there is a syntax error line 36.  Can you please identify which line is line 36?  I only counted 32 lines in the code you posted.

Comment: Line 36 is the last end statement.  I commented out some lines in the document hence the 32 lines of code instead of 36.  

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have one extra `end`

As [@david-grayson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446194/485864) states, had your indentations been correct, you may have spotted it.

This of course, is given the code as you presented it here.  It may not be exactly that, though the error message matches the found issue.

Here is the code with indentation, some style changes, and no syntax errors:

```
require 'awesome_print'
require 'rexml/document'
require 'debugger'

include REXML

class Scrapper
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize
    file = File.new('./cia-1996.xml')
    @data = REXML::Document.new(file)
  end

  def get_country_inflation
    inflation_hash = {}
    XPath.match(data, '//country').map do |element|
      inflation_hash[element.attributes['name']] = element.attributes['inflation'].to_i
    end
    nested_array = inflation_hash.to_a
    sorted_array = nested_array.sort_by do |country, inflation_value|
      inflation_value
    end.reverse
    puts 'The countries with the highest inflation indexes in 1996 were:'
    first_five = sorted_array.first(5)
    first_five.each do |item|
      puts "#{item[0]}, with an inflation index of #{item[1]}"
    end
  end
end

sample = Scrapper.new
sample.get_country_inflation
```

Comment: … thank you very much for revealing my errors explicitly.  It made all the difference. I think I will stick to using do and end statements for a while (at least until I become more experienced).

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is messed up starting here:

```
XPath.match( data, "//country").map { |element| 
  inflation_hash[element.attributes["name"]] = element.attributes["inflation"].to_i}
  nested_array = inflation_hash.to_a
```

The last line of that excerpt should be unindented by one level because the block you passed to "map" was terminated on the second line by the right bracket.

Try fixing that and everything after it.

Also, here is a tip: always write multi-line blocks using `do` and `end` and put the `end` on its own line.  Then you could would be:

```
XPath.match( data, "//country").map do |element| 
  inflation_hash[element.attributes["name"]] = element.attributes["inflation"].to_i
end
nested_array = inflation_hash.to_a
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will do the edits right now and see what happens! 

PS: I like your tip; my instructor also urges us to do the same. I was running away from doing more typing but will now follow you guys tips (esp. since it will help with errors of this sort). Thank you once again:)